# Error - "cannot infer type for parameter 'rowType'" when using the find function with MongoDB in Ballerina

Tags: mongodb, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm encountering an error with the Ballerina programming language while querying data from my MongoDB using the find function. The error message I'm getting is: 'cannot infer type for parameter 'rowType'. I have also attached an image of my query method for reference. Can you assist me in resolving this issue?"

This is my code line.

`map<json>[] response = check self.mongoClient->find("stores", (), search_query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the API doc related to the `find` operation
https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerinax/mongodb/4.3.0#Client

Its return type is `stream<rowType, error?> | Error`

This sample might be useful for you
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-mongodb/blob/08170e793ac0fb1a642a5a441621968e5134c57d/mongodb/samples/query.bal#L42 (but this is a little bit old)

We can do something like this:

```
type Store {
    string name;
    string address;
    anydata...;
} 

stream<Store, error?> found = check mongoClient->find("stores", filter = {name: "Joe Market"});
```

`Store` is the type of record we are expecting from the collection.